# Нужна ли авторизация в приложении

Tags: android, ios, авторизация

Часто замечаю что во многих приложениях(сервисах, информационных справочниках и т.д.) реализована авторизация, будь то посредством самого приложения или же через социальные сети.
Вопрос, зачем это делать, если приложение простое ну или не носит в себе надобность(*взгляд со стороны начинающего разработчика*).

Хорошо, допустим было принято решение реализовать авторизацию у себя в приложении. Как мы можем эту информацию использовать для себя(вытаскивать мейлы и делать рассылку к примеру)?

Comment: например, после авторизации через соцсети на стену кинуть информацию о ПО.\n
2) использовать для чата или рейтинга
3) для сохранения историй в ПО, чтобы в будущем клиент на новом устройстве загрузил данные свои

Comment: Авторизация нужна только если нужна. Делать её абы была - это некрасибо по отношению к пользователю + я думаю даже будет минимальный шанс завалить апп ревью. А так скорее всего делают авторизации для сбора макс инфы по пользователям. Раньше ещё делалась для шары в соцсети, но сейчас уже повсеместно другой подход к этому используется

Answer (score 1):

Собирать статистику, полагаю. Следить за тем, сколько людей используют приложение, их какие-то личные данные(пол, возраст, местонахождение) и уже по этим данным можно поменять интерфейс, стили какие-нибудь, ну или добавить новые функции.

Comment: firebase соберет такие данные из без авторизации)

Comment: @iFr0z освоить бы его еще как надо) вообще тяжело внедрять его в приложение?

Comment: @iFr0z, не всякий разработчик использует только готовые решения, много тех, кто любит "велосипеды")

Comment: @VadimMorozov http://netpeak.net/ru/blog/nastraivaem-analitiku-mobilnyh-prilozheniy-s-pomoshchyu-firebase-analytics/ ничего трудного нет, поверьте:) только клацать мышкой так сказать т.е. без доп кода собирает: first_open,in_app_purchase,user_engagement,session_start,app_update, app_remove, os_update, app_clear_data, app_exception и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Если приложение имеет какой-то набор данных, которые можно (или нужно) закрепить за определённым пользователем (userId), то и авторизация нужна соответственно. Других причин не вижу.